# Design patterns for validating a file

Tags: java, design-patterns, validation, file-upload

We have to validate a CSV file containing various configuration parameters.  Are there any standard design patterns to do this type of validation.

More details:

- There are different types of records - each with their own validation logic
- Certain records cross reference other records
- There are rules on the order of the records
- There are rules on the eligibility of duplicate records
- etc

Comment: Yes the pattern is called "markup language" -- XML is a good example of this -- and its used all over the place in JAVA. failing that you have to code complex CSV parsers -- which is not fun.

Comment: We are stuck with the CSV format sadly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [*Strategy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern to for validating the records. Have an abstract base class to represent a Record and you can use 
[*Factory Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) ,or  *Simple Factory*  to create concrete instances of various Record types.
Your specification is not complete. Here is the code sample that implements Strategy pattern
with a simplistic assumption about your record.

```
interface Validator {
     // since it is not clear what are the attributes that matter for a record, 
     // this takes an instance of Record. 
     // Modify to accept relevant attribures of Record
     public boolean validate (Record r);
 }

 class ConcreteValidator implements Validator {
      // implements a validation logic
 }

// implements Comparable so that it can be used in rules that compare Records
abstract class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
    protected Validator v;
    abstract void setValidator(Validator v);
    public boolean isValid() {
        return v.validate(this);
    }
}

class ConcreteRecord extends Record {
   // alternatively accept a Validaor during the construction itself 
   // by providing a constructor that accepts a type of Validator
   // i.e. ConcreteRecord(Validator v) ...
    void setValidator(Validator v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    // implementation of method from Comparable Interface
    public int compareTo(final Record o) {... }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Store the read in Records in a List (allows duplicates)
        List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
        // this is simplistic. Your Record creation mode might be 
        // more complex, And you can use a Factory Method 
        // (or Simple Factory) for creation of  ConcreteRecord
        Record r = new ConcreteRecord();
        r.setValidtor(new ConcretedValidator());
        if (r.isValid()) {
            // store only valid records
            recordList.add(r);
        }

       // do further processing of Records stored in recordList
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template pattern may help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

You set up a scaffolding for your validation in general terms, then hand off the algorithm to a delegate that knows how to handle specifics at various points.

Answer (score -1):

I know a friend of mine uses [JBOSS DROOLS](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) to validate this kind of files.